# asp.net change marker size with onmouseover event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, mschart

I'm using Microsoft Chart Control in asp.net, for a line chart, how can I change the marker size when the mouse is over a particular point?

Comment: This question is too vague: which line chart? do you mean in Javascript? what did you try? can show any code?

Comment: Are you using a javascript framework like jQuery? What kind of chart? Since the MS chart control is a server-side thing, you need to figure out a way to map its output to something you can analyze on the client. The answer to this question will probably involve a lot of things: ajax, javascript, image maps. It may not be trivial. The performance may not be acceptable since you need the server to re-render changes. It may be easier to use a client-side charting tool instead. Much more information, an example, etc. is needed.

Comment: MS Chart control has very few client-side modules that can be manipulated. The only trick I know to capture a mouse event is to update the MapAreaAtribute to be sth like "onmouseover=...". However, within this piece of code it is hard to understand which specific point is the one mouse over.

Comment: can you paste the markup code and the html generated for that particular control?

Comment: i found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/MSWinWebChart/thread/52c1ea0b-195e-4c6b-a8d1-70c6fe8d4f51) on msdn forums, then bumped into this question, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably get some help from here: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx

However, I would recommend using something like ChartFX or Dundas charts or Highcharts (pure JS charting) which have greater flexibility and better API for these type of things.